# Pendulum attached to Oscillating Fulcrum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

In the specific scheme, I would expect that by pulling the spring to the right, the pendulum due to inertia would have to move to the left quartile. In order to find the r vector:

$$r = R + l$$

and derive the equations of motion using Lagrangian, I would use:
$$l = (-l\sinθ)i + (-l\cosθ)j$$

However, all tutorials I saw have $l$ as
$$l = (l\sinθ)i + (l\cosθ)j,$$

which means that the pendulum, following a displacement to the right, it also moves to the right.

Is the thought all wrong on this?[image]

Comment: depends on the sign convention of the angle $\theta$. If $\theta$ is defined to be positive when you rotate the arm counter-clockwise from the y-axis, then the tutorial you mention is correct. If the sign convention is opposite, what you describe is correct for the situation you have drawn.

Comment: I understand that the theta that I took here is negative, and thus both sine and cosine are negative, thus the -l*sin(theta), becomes positive.

Comment: ...which means the x-component is to the right? That is not what your figure says.

Comment: the theta I have chosen in the figure is clockwise; the angle is in the 3rd quartile, thus negative. Which means it has negative sine and cosine. If I got what you indicated, it means that I can declare this direction as negative and say for example that θ = -φ. This way, the sin(-φ) would be -sin(φ) and the x-component would be positive. The cosine does't change. 
But, if I choose my angle θ to be in the 4th quartile and counter-clockwise, the cosine will be positive and the sine still negative. Did I get well what you meant?

Comment: @Alex The quadrant the ray lies in does not determine the angle's sign. What matters is the direction you took to get to that position and what direction you define as positive. If you are defining this angle to be negative, where an angle of $0$ corresponds to aligned with the positive x-axis, and if you are taking your angle to be the angle swept out when you move through the 4th quadrant to the third, then your sign convention is clockwise is negative and counter-clockwise is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing out the Lagrangian, we are not exactly concerned about which direction the pendulum would move when you move the spring, we just care that it *moves*, which is why the tutorials show the $\hat{i}$ to be positive. The fact that it will conserve momentum and move the opposite direction from the spring will come out after you've solved for the equation of motion.

Comment: thanks for this clarification. The thing is that if I consider the first equation with the minus, then the equations that occur from the Lagrangian, differ significantly from the case where the x-component is positive. I would expect the minus to cancel out some way or remain and reappear in other parts of the equations, indicating the as you said, the opposite directions; however, this does not happen. In any case, given that as you nicely said, we work with the Lagrangian, I would expect that the solutions would be the same